# Maximum Sum of Non-Adjacent Elements runtime error addition of unsigned offset

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, dynamic-programming

I was solving house robber problem of leetcode using dynamic programming and leetcode is giving me
Line 1034: Char 34: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x6020000000b0 overflowed to 0x6020000000ac (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:34

where did i go wrong ?

```
class Solution {
public:
int solveUtil(int ind, vector<int>& arr, vector<int>& dp){

if(dp[ind]!=-1) return dp[ind];

if(ind==0) return arr[ind];
if(ind<0)  return 0;

int pick= arr[ind]+ solveUtil(ind-2, arr,dp);
int nonPick = 0 + solveUtil(ind-1, arr, dp);

return dp[ind]=max(pick, nonPick);
  }

int rob(vector<int>& nums) {
    int n = nums.size();
  vector<int> dp(n,-1);
return solveUtil(n-1,nums, dp);
}
};
```

Comment: What data do you have in `nums` when you call `rob`? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: What is the constraint? That you can't pick two adjacent items?

Answer (score 0):

This like looks suspicious:

```
if(dp[ind]!=-1) return dp[ind];
```

When you invoke solveUtil(ind-1) or solveUtil(ind-2), you could easily be passing a value of `ind` less than zero.

Should be:

```
if ((ind >= 0) && (dp[ind] != -1))
{
   return dp[ind];     
}
```

Or just re-order your lines:

```
if(ind==0) return arr[ind];
if(ind<0)  return 0;
if(dp[ind]!=-1) return dp[ind];
```

Comment: second on worked like charm , thanks